# JFreechart LookUpPaintScale color gradient

Tags: gradient, scale, jfreechart, lookup, paint

How do you add a color gradient (3 colors: red, yellow, Green) to a [`LookUpPaintScale`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/LookupPaintScale.html) in JFreechart?
Thanks

Comment: I tried initializing it with the new GradientPaint, but this only take 2 colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried initializing it with the new `GradientPaint`, but this only take 2 colors.

You could try [`LinearGradientPaint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
....

XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(data1, xAxis, yAxis, null);

    LookupPaintScale ps = new LookupPaintScale(0,101,Color.lightGray);
    ps.add(0, Color.green);
    ps.add(10, Color.yellow);
    ps.add(20, Color.red);

    renderer1.setBlockHeight(0.95f);
    renderer1.setBlockWidth(0.95f);

    renderer1.setPaintScale(ps);
    plot.setRenderer(renderer1);

....
```

Comment: Please, help - how to get the renderer1 ? I've done it by this:
final XYItemRenderer renderer1 = plot.getRenderer();
but there is no acceptible method setBlockHeight() in such way

Comment: You should create a new renderer: XYBlockRenderer renderer = new XYBlockRenderer(); and set this renderer to plot: plot.setRenderer(renderer);